# Does anyone have a Toshiba Thrive or similar tablet AVD for development in Eclipse?

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going to implement rosjava on a Toshiba Thrive and would love to be able to emulate the thrive in Eclipse. Does anyone know how to best accomplish this? I ask because all the Android tutorials and web searches I've done in trying to find out how to set up the AVD for a tablet PC has not been very successful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43382/does-anyone-have-a-toshiba-thrive-or-similar-tablet-avd-for-development-in-eclipse?/) by [101010](https://answers.ros.org/users/3108/101010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2012-09-07

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While you *are* trying to use rosjava, this isn't really a question about ROS. I'd suggest asking this question on an Android development forum.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2